# Intercept android app DNS lookup with Frida

Tags: android, frida

I have been attempting to intercept when an app performs a DNS lookup using Frida. I assumed that ultimately a DNS lookup will end up in a libc call to `gethostbyname` or  `getaddrinfo` but this does not seem to be the case. For example this Frida trace command does not hit either function

```
frida-trace -U -i "gethostbyname" -i "getaddrinfo" "com.android.my_app"
```

According the answer to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218015/how-does-android-do-dns-name-resolution) question, the `netd` daemon might be responsible for DNS resolution on android

> "DNS lookups are centralized in the netd daemon to allow for
> system-wide caching, while apps call functions (such as getaddrinfo)
> in Bionic. The query is sent over a UNIX socket to
> /dev/socket/dnsproxyd to the netd daemon, which parses the request and
> calls getaddrinfo again to issue DNS lookups, then caches the results
> so that other apps can use them."

However hooking this daemon doesn't result in any hits either:

```
frida-trace -U -i "gethostbyname" -i "getaddrinfo" "netd"
```

I am new to Frida so I am not sure if I am missing something here. I would appreciate some insight into how I can hook the DNS lookup call

Comment: The functions are being hooked properly as far as I can tell and handlers are being created. I will explore a few other options and try to update this question

Comment: Is the app base on standard DEX code (e.g. compiled from Java or Kotlin) or does it use a different framework like Xamarin, ReactNative, Dart? Some of those language may implement DNS resolving on their own so that it works on all platforms. I do remember that Firefox for Android e.g. does implement DNS resolving on it's own.

Comment: @Robert this is just a standard Kotlin app. I believe I found the function performing the lookup. Its android_getaddrinfofornet which is present in the libc that my Android app is using